# I get error in the log for Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/db2heroku-buildpack-php'

Tags: php, ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry, devops

when i use cf push myapp -b https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php in the log, it says

2016-03-04T11:35:16.893-0500
[STG/0]
err
Cloning into '/tmp/buildpacks/db2heroku-buildpack-php'...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you tell us more about what your app is and what you are trying to do with it?

Comment: i am just using simple php file and <?php
$str = "Hello world!";
print $str;
?>

Comment: i used DashDB as my Database for doing a blog using php: https://hub.jazz.net/project/ibmdatabase/dashDB/overview#https://hub.jazz.net/git/ibmdatabase%252FdashDB/list/master/samples/dashDBPHP

Comment: Never mind i have resolved the issue

Answer (score 0):

The right command to use is:

`cf push myapp -b https://github.com/ibmdb/db2heroku-buildpack-php.git`